# HTML background with 2 images

Tags: html, css

I have one picture that is 50px width and 340px height. The picture should be repeat to the left side, but not down. Then i have a streak with this picture in the top of my page. And the rest of the page(down) should be an other picture.

Here is my statement:

```
background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top #2C9E2E;
```

But now i want to change the last piece `#2C9E2` to `url("images/bg-body.gif")`, but it wont work.

I tried this code:

```
body{
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top url("images/bg-body.gif");
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that you tried. How did you try to replace it? Show us your code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background` is shorthand for multiple declarations, and the `url("images/bg.png")` and `#2C9E2E` pieces specify `background-image` and `background-color`, respectively.

To display multiple, layered, backgrounds you need to separate multiple declarations with a comma (`background: <top background>, <bottom background>`).  Also, the color declaration can only appear on the last background layer.

So, if you want bg.png to appear on top of bg-body.png with a flat colour behind both, you would use:

```
background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top, url("images/bg-body.gif") #2C9E2E;
```

Add additional properties to the second background as needed (e.g. repeat/scroll/position), and remove the color value if you don't want it behind both of your images.

---

Also note that multiple backgrounds are not supported by IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).  If you need to support IE8 or older, you will need to specify a single background fallback.

```
background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top #2C9E2E;
background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top, url("images/bg-body.gif") #2C9E2E;
```